# Office-js - Excel ribbon buttons are displayed on desktop, but not on Excel on the web

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

So I'm trying to create some shortcuts for my add in that are accessed via add-in command buttons on the ribbon. The buttons appear on desktop excel, but not in excel on the web. This is a problem for me, since it seems like the only reliable way to debug an add-in is via office on the web and a browser debugger.

My manifest passes validation, and I'm not getting any feedback in the browser console, so I have no idea what the problem is. The relevant portion of my manifest is here:

```
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="PlaidCloudAddin.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="PlaidCloudAddin.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
            <OfficeTab id="TabData">
              <Group id="PlaidCommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="PlaidButtons.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="PullAllButton">
                  <Label resid="PullAllButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="PullAllButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="PullAllButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>syncAll</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="PullOneButton">
                  <Label resid="PullOneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="PullOneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="PullOneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>syncOne</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
```

Note that the default "show taskpane" button that was created as part of the template shows up and works, just not the two buttons I added.

For context, this is what my Data ribbon looks like now:
[image: Excel Data tab]

Comment: Does it make a difference whether you are using single-line ribbon or multline ribbon?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I have no way to change between the two. I have no toggle in the view tab, and the caret in the bottom-right of the ribbon just collapses the ribbon, it doesn't switch any style. I've edited my original post with a picture of what my data ribbon looks like in Excel online (with the missing buttons, not that they're much to look at).

Comment: That collapsed ribbon is the single-line ribbon. In Excel on the web, in the green title bar at the top, near the right end of the bar, you should see a sliding toggle button that switches between single-line ribbon and multiline ribbon. I'm wondering if your buttons appear on one but not the other, or they not appear on either?

Comment: Ah, in that case it doesn't make a difference. I've seen the toggle you're talking about in other peoples' screenshots, but it doesn't appear for me. The screenshot I edited into my original post is Excel online running in Edge 84.0.522.63. All I have is the caret, both in desktop Excel and Excel online.

Comment: FYI this is still an issue. I'm not getting any feedback in the browser console, manifest validator, debug logs, etc, so I'm flying pretty much completely blind trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Try raising this issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.